# Call objective-c method from C library

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cross-platform, lib

I have a cross platform library written in C (.a) to do cryptographic stuff.

I use it that way on Android

```
+------------------------+           +-----------------+
|      Android (Java)    |           |  Android (Java) |
+------------------------+           +-----------------+
   1.|              /|\               3.|           /|\
    \|/            4.|                 \|/         2.|
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                    myFramework.a (C)                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

So the following function is called by Java, then call Java for something not related to the previous "context"

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#include "jni.h"

static JNIEnv *gEnv;
static jobject gObj;

int doStuff(char* aString) { /* have fun calling java */ }

#else

#include "oni.h" // objective c native interface ? :3

#endif
```

This function will use **JNIEnv** and **jobject** to access Java methods.

I have included the C library in the iOS project but can't find a way to call an objective-c method from the C library (part 2. and 3.)

**How can I call an objective-c method from a C library?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely call Objective-C methods from C functions. To do so, however, you will need to make sure that your C function has a reference to an Objective-C object of some kind. Your example above doesn't show that.

So, you might write your function as:

```
int doStuff(id ref, char* aString) {
  [ref objcMethod];
  ....
  return 0;
}
```

Or maybe you would store the `ref` in static storage in your library, so that it was available to all functions, without passing it explicitly. It really depends on your use-case. Remember that Classes are objects, too, in Objective-C; so if you need ref to be a class (for a static methods), that can work, too.

There is a tangential topic. Sometimes, in Objective-C you want a direct reference to a method implementation so that you can invoke it directly. This is handy in tight loops, where performance is required. If this is your need, [this blog post](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/macsploitation/bypassing-objectivecs-message-passing-mechanism-for-speed-24946) goes into the topic.

Comment: How could I get the **id** type in a framework written in C if there is no equivalent to **jni.h**?
I understand that I can call an objective-c method from c when this C file is compiled in xcode, but this is not the case here. I need to find a way to bridge from C compiled with gcc or something to C compiled with xCode (then having also **id** ref to call objective-c)

Comment: To answer the first part, just like you would #include "jni.h", you would need to #include "objc/objc.h". To answer the second part, if you plan on calling Objective-C from C, you're going to be using an Objective-C compiler. This is fine, as it's a superset of C. Just like you need to #ifdef your Android specific code, you will do so for the objc code too. To keep the function signatures shared between the platforms, I suggest you just a static global var for the object ref, like you already have for Android in the example.

Comment: Also, in case it isn't clear, this isn't just "for Xcode". The Objective-C runtime is available from gcc as well as Xcode or clang.

Comment: To clarify the point I was making, you can call Objective-C methods from code that has a C interface, but if it contains Objective-C code, it's Objective-C code with a C wrapper around it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't. C can't invoke Objective-C methods.

That said, Objective-C is a pure superset of C, so you can write C functions in your Objective-C code. Those functions need to have a pure C interface, but internally they can contain Objective-C code. So you need to create a C public interface (Which can be implemented in a mix of C and Objective-C) and call that from your C library.

### EDIT:

Actually, you could probably use the Objective-C runtime, which is written in C, to call the C interface to your Objective-C methods. I've dabbled with the Objective-C runtime, but not enough to know it fluently. (Plus I've worked mostly in Swift for long enough now that even my "vanilla" Objective-C is getting rusty.)

Comment: Great! I get the big picture, but I am not sure about how to "call that code from your C library". Could you explain more on how to interface the C library. Should I create an objC lib (with pure C function to bridge) and then load dynamically this from the c lib?

Comment: Good point: even if the library was written with pure-C interfaces, if the functions call Objective-C the library is then an Objective-C library (e.g. effects what flags it's compiled with, etc). I'd still call it a C library, but it technically isn't anymore, really.